# Python 2.7, how to store multiple fields into seperate list

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am opening a large text file in read mode. I was able to split the data by commas and strip it from all white space. Now I am trying to store each field into a separate list.

Example of the data:

```
Montgomery,2327375.079,1273061.532,3 ,3 
Stanly,2224024.174,1267300.181,5 ,5 
Henderson,1559580.515,1277200.634,5 ,5
```

Current code:

```
county = []
x_coor = []
y_coor = []
observed = []
expected = []

for line in lines:
        for value in line.split(','):
            value = value.strip()
```

I believe my next step would be, `county.append[value]` but when I tried that and printed county, it printed:

```
[['3']] [['3'], ['5']] [['3'], ['5'], ['5']]
```

Does anyone have any guidance on how to write each column into it's own individual list?

Comment: better to paste your next step

Comment: next step: county.append([value])
      print county,

Comment: you can remove the whitespaces with `line = line.replace(' ','')`

Comment: @TiffanyMorris you are appending a `list`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're pretty close! I would iterate over all of the lines, splitting each on the comma character to create the underlying row of data. Then, append each individual component of the row to its appropriate list:

```
county = []
x_coor = []
y_coor = []
observed = []
expected = []

for line in lines:
    row = line.split(',')

    county.append(row[0])
    x_coor.append(row[1])
    y_coor.append(row[2])
    observed.append(row[3])
    expected.append(row[4])
```

Comment: I was typing the same solution half way.

Comment: Thank you Paul. If I need to split and strip the data, would I add row = line.strip()  under row = line.split(',') ?

Comment: After we say `row = line.split(",")`, `row` is an array consisting of the comma-separated contents of `line`. So, we should say `row = line.strip().split(',')` in a single line to ensure that there is no trailing or leading whitespace on the line :)

Comment: Just to follow up, if you want every individual element to have its whitespace stripped, you should strip the whitespace from each element via `row[0].split()` and so on.

Comment: That seemed to work but the output is repeating itself. Example, ['Montgomery']
['Montgomery', 'Stanly']
['Montgomery', 'Stanly', 'Henderson']

Comment: Sorry! I meant to say `row[0].strip()` in my last comment! All due apologies.

Comment: I tried that as well but I get the same output: ['Montgomery']
['Montgomery', 'Stanly']
['Montgomery', 'Stanly', 'Henderson']

Answer (score 1):

An arguably more pythonic way of doing this would be through list comprehensions.  Say you have a .csv file named "file.csv" containing the data.  The following would give you what you want:

```
import csv
with open('file.csv', 'rb') as data:
    reader = csv.reader(data)
    awesome_list = list(reader)

county = [x[0] for x in awesome_list]
x_coor = [x[1] for x in awesome_list]
y_coor = [x[2] for x in awesome_list]
observed = [x[3] for x in awesome_list]
expected = [x[4] for x in awesome_list]
```